# MVC store Captcha Answer for Registration page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have  an MVC web application which uses Captcha code, I am storing Captcha answer in session variable. The issue here is, when user open registeration page and for some reason he leaves the page ideal for 20minutes and gets back and submits the registration form  by filling the details when I validate the data I am loosing the Captcha answer stored in session variable and feel its inappropriate to ask him refresh the page. Wondering what could be the ideal solution\best practice to store Captcha answer in MVC so that it can be shared across actions.Any suggestion\help would be of gr8 help.

Regards,
HSR.

Comment: Why do you need to share it across across actions?

Comment: Well I need it tobe storef from one action to another i.e. when the random text is generated in one action and then validate it on RegisterAction.